# Fastest popcount per limb in an AVX register

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I'm looking for a faster way to compute the popcount (number of ones) per 64bit limb in a 256bit wide AVX register.

My current approach is the following:

```
    const __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
            /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
            /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
            /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4,
            /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
            /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
            /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
            /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4
    );

    __m256i popcount_avx2_64(const __m256i vec) {
        const __m256i low_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0f);
        const __m256i lo  = _mm256_and_si256(vec, low_mask);
        const __m256i hi  = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(vec, 4), low_mask);
        const __m256i popcnt1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, lo);
        const __m256i popcnt2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, hi);
        __m256i local = _mm256_setzero_si256();
        local = _mm256_add_epi8(local, popcnt1);
        local = _mm256_add_epi8(local, popcnt2);
    
        const __m256i mask2 = _mm256_set1_epi64x(0xff);
        __m256i ret;
        
        ret = _mm256_add_epi8(local, _mm256_srli_epi32(local,  8));
        ret = _mm256_add_epi8(ret, _mm256_srli_epi32(ret,  16));
        ret = _mm256_add_epi8(ret, _mm256_srli_epi64(ret,  32));
        ret = _mm256_and_si256(ret, mask2);
        return ret;
    }
```

This code looks up for each `uint8_t` limb its popcount and afterwards adds those values up in each 64bit limb. The original code, from which this one was adapted, can be found [here](https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount/blob/master/popcnt-avx2-lookup.cpp).

But in contrast to the linked repo I'm not interested in computing the hamming weight of large values, but rather of very small (64 bit bounded) ones but a lot of them. E.g. I'm getting a list of `2**30` values, and I want to find all entries with hamming weight below a given and constant threshold.

Thanks to @chtz this is my current solution

```
    const __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
            /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
            /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
            /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4,
            /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
            /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
            /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
            /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4
    );
    const __m256i low_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0f);

    __m256i popcount_avx2_64(const __m256i vec) noexcept {
        const __m256i lo  = _mm256_and_si256(vec, low_mask);
        const __m256i hi  = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(vec, 4), low_mask);
        const __m256i popcnt1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, lo);
        const __m256i popcnt2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, hi);
        const __m256i local = _mm256_add_epi8(popcnt2, popcnt1);
        const __m256i ret =_mm256_sad_epu8 (local, _mm256_setzero_si256());
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: The final reduction can be done using `_mm256_sad_epu8(_mm256_setzero_si256(), _mm256_add_epi8(popcnt1, popcnt2));`

Comment: OK wow, didn't know this instructions, but its awesome, Thank You!

Comment: Ice Lake and later have AVX-512VPOPCNT, for `vpopcntq` which does exactly what you want in one instruction.  (Except on Alder Lake and other hybrids where Intel doesn't expose AVX512 at all.)  Otherwise yeah, Wojciech Mula's implementations are your best bet, stopping after `vpsadbw` without reduction across elements.  That makes Harley-Seal unusable or not worth it, I think.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was aware of AVX512 intrinsics solving my problem. But sadly none of our servers has it. So I need to go with avx2.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the tags, that's why I only commented about a related problem.  Anyway, please don't edit answers into the question itself; post that as an answer (yes, to your own question; that's encouraged if you solve it yourself, even if it was with hints from comments.)

Comment: *`const __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8( ...`*  - don't do that at global scope; compilers are bad at this and will actually copy from an anonymous initializer in `.rodata` into `lookup` in `.bss`, basically failing to fully constant-propagate through `_mm256_setr_epi8`.  Put constants like that inside function scope, or make them plain arrays that you load with `_mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_load_si128((void*)lookup))` or something.